# Read same extension multiple files in one directory in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, fastq

I currently have an issue with reading files in one directory.
I need to take all the fastq files in a file and run the script for each file then put new files in an ‘Edited_sequences’ folder.
The one script I had is

```
perl -ne '$i++; if($i<80001){print}' BM2003_TCCCAGAACAAC_L001_R1_001.fastq > ./Edited_sequences/BM2003_TCCCAGAACAAC_L001_R1_001.fastq
```

It takes the first 80000 lines in one fastq file then outputs the result.
Now for example I have 2000 fastq files, then I need to copy and paste for 2000 times.
I know there is a glob command suit for this situation but I just do not know how to deal with that.
Please help me out.

Comment: I suppose you mean "all files in a directory with a .fastq extension." What about `*.fastq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use perl to do copy/paste for you, first argument `*.fastq` are all fastq files, and second `./Edited_sequences` is target folder for new files,

```
perl -e '$d=pop; `head -8000 "$_" > "$d/$_"` for @ARGV' *.fastq ./Edited_sequences
```

Answer (score 0):

[`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) gets you an array of filenames matching a particular expression. It's frequently used with `<>` brackets, a lot like reading input (you can think of it as reading files from a directory).

This is a simple example that will print the names of every ".fastq" file in the current directory:

```
print "$_\n" for <*.fastq>;
```

The important part is `<*.fastq>`, which gives us an array of filenames matching that expression (in this case, a file extension). If you need to change which directory your Perl script is working in, you can use [`chdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html).

From there, we can process your files as needed:

```
while (my $filename = <*.fastq>) {
    open(my $in, '<', $filename) or die $!;
    open(my $out, '>', "./Edited_sequences/$filename") or die $!;

    for (1..80000) {
        my $line = <$in>;
        print $out $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- Use Perl to read in the 2000 files and run it as part of your program
- Use the Shell to pass each of those 2000 file to your command line

Here's the bash alternative:

```
for file in *.fastq
do
    perl -ne '$i++; if($i<80001){print}' "$file" > "./Edited_sequences/$file"
done
```

Your same Perl script, but with the shell finding each file. This *should* work and not overload the command line. The `for` loop in bash, if handed a glob can expand them correctly.

However, I always recommend that you don't actually execute the command, but echo the resulting commands into a file:

```
for file in *.fastq
do
    echo "perl -ne '\$i++; if(\$i<80001){print}' \
\"$file\" > \"./Edited_sequences/$file\""    >> myoutput.txt
done
```

Then, you can look at `myoutput.txt` to make sure it looks good before you actually do any real harm. Once you've determined that `myoutput.txt` is a good file, you can execute that as a shell script:

```
$ bash myoutput.txt
```